# Java applet to get available RAM slots or total capacity with available capacity

Tags: java, jar, applet, ram

I am trying to get the memory slots available in any system using a browser applet. i signed it so that it has permission at user end.

I used Interface `OperatingSystemMXBean getTotalPhysicalMemorySize`

It will be fine if i can get the total possible capacity and currently installed ram size. Code is as below

```
com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean mxbean = (com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean)ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();
g.drawString("TotalRAM:"+mxbean.getTotalSwapSpaceSize()/(1024*1024*1024)+""+"GB",50,240);
g.drawString("RAM SIZE :" + (mxbean.getTotalPhysicalMemorySize()/(1024*1024*1024))+ " GB ",50,260);
```

Comment: What do you mean by memory slots?  Do you mean you want to find if the motherboard has free memory banks?

Comment: This is very hard to do even in C.  I imagine this is the sort of functionality Java might have one day (as it is useful for collecting inventory information) it is very low level compared to the features that were added in Java 7 for example. e.g. Java 7 is the first to support symbolic links.

Comment: There might be a way to do what you suggest in VB which you can call from Java. (I don't know what it is)

Comment: What i suggested is already Java and i am using it to get several related details but not the actual slots.

Comment: Yes, the methods in your question are in the HotSpot JVM (not all JVMs will have this internal use class) but details like which slots are used are not.

Comment: Rightly said Peter.. I am still wondering about the solution.. I think SMBIOS can help, what do you think ?

Comment: @G.N.Vashishtha Hmm, you can easily get the server system info, but client system varies. It can be any OS, any hardware arch etc. You may need to handle every thing in C. But i think it may be possible in Java.